# Mysql cannot write to a persistent volume that minikube creates

Tags: mysql, macos-sierra, minikube

I am trying to deploy a minikube mysql pod that has a persistent volume using a hostPath to either the /data or /Users directory on a Mac host. However the directory that is created always has the wrong permissions and mysql is unable to access or write to the directory. If I run `minikube ssh` and run `chmod -R 777 /data/db/` then mysql runs fine. Is there any way to get minikube to set the correct permissions?

the error I get is

```
2017-05-08 23:22:45 23 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2017-05-08 23:22:45 23 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2017-05-08 23:22:45 23 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2017-05-08 23:22:45 23 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2017-05-08 23:22:45 23 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2017-05-08 23:22:45 23 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2017-05-08 23:22:45 23 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2017-05-08 23:22:45 23 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2017-05-08 23:22:45 23 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2017-05-08 23:22:45 7fb9598ee740  InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory.
2017-05-08 23:22:45 7fb9598ee740  InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory.
2017-05-08 23:22:45 23 [ERROR] InnoDB: Creating or opening ./ibdata1 failed!
2017-05-08 23:22:45 23 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not open or create the system tablespace. If you tried to add new data files to the system tablespace, and it failed here, you should now edit innodb_data_file_path in my.cnf back to what it was, and remove the new ibdata files InnoDB created in this failed attempt. InnoDB only wrote those files full of zeros, but did not yet use them in any way. But be careful: do not remove old data files which contain your precious data!
2017-05-08 23:22:45 23 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2017-05-08 23:22:45 23 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2017-05-08 23:22:45 23 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2017-05-08 23:22:45 23 [ERROR] Aborting
```

my container definition is

```
spec: {
      containers: [
        {
          name: 'percona',
          image: 'percona:5.6',
          env: [
            {
              name: 'MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD',
              value: secrets['system-mysql-root-password'],
            },
            {
              name: 'MYSQL_OPS_USER',
              value: variables['system-mysql-ops-user'],
            },
            {
              name: 'MYSQL_OPS_PASSWORD',
              value: secrets['system-mysql-ops-password'],
            },
            {
              name: 'MYSQL_APP_USER',
              value: variables['system-mysql-app-user'],
            },
            {
              name: 'MYSQL_APP_PASSWORD',
              value: secrets['system-mysql-app-password'],
            },
          ],
          ports: [
            {
              containerPort: 3306,
              protocol: 'TCP',
            },
          ],
          volumeMounts: [
            { name: 'data', mountPath: '/var/lib/mysql' },
            { name: 'conf', mountPath: '/etc/mysql/conf.d' },
          ],
        },
      ],
      volumes: [
        { name: 'data', hostPath: { path: '/data/db/database' } },
        { name: 'conf', hostPath: { path: '/data/db/database-conf' } },
      ],
    },
```

and the default permission of the directory created by minikube

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 May  8 23:22 database
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 May  8 23:22 database-conf
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1. 
Change the permission on the host to e.g. 777.

Solution 2. (better)
Change the volume owner to mysql user by container start. For docker (Dockerfile):

```
...
CMD chown mysql:mysql -R /data/db/
```

Solution 3. start mysql with root user ;)

Comment: 1. & 2. The host is the minikube VM so I cannot change the permissions 3. probably not the best solution for security

Comment: Do you use docker or some other container engine?